# Javascript to show any/all query values in the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I am working on a document list with a filter menu to pair down the listing via query strings.  I want to display all current query values in a designated div, which I have working. The problem that I have now is that I have each category individually coded in the JS, which causes an "undefined" value to display if there is no query for that category.

I want to display ONLY the values that are represented in the query.  I have been trying to create an array, but my JS is spotty at best and this has been kludged-together from multiple sources. 
Any suggestions?
Here is my current js:

```
 function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
    try{
            q = location.search.substring(1);
            v = q.split("&");
            for( var i = 0; i < v.length; i++ ){
                p = v[i].split("=");
                if( p[0] == variable ){
                    if( p[1].indexOf('_') != -1 ){
                        n = [];
                        for( var j = 0; j < p[1].split('_').length; j++ ){
                            n.push(p[1].split('_')[j]);
                        }
                        str = "";
                        for( var k = 0; k < n.length; k++ ){
                            str += n[k] + ' ';
                        }
                        return str.trim();
                    }
                    else{
                        return p[1];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (e){
            console.log(e);
        }
}




if(document.location.search.length) {
// query string exists
$p( "div#filterContainer" ).html( 
         "<div class='litType'><ul class='ct-list'><li class='ct-list-elem'>"
         +getQueryVariable('application')
         +"</li>"+
         "<li class='ct-list-elem'>"
         +getQueryVariable('year')
         +"</li>"+
         "<li class='ct-list-elem'>"
         +getQueryVariable('industry')+
         "</li>"+
         "<li class='ct-list-elem'>"
         +getQueryVariable('literature_type')
         +
          "</li></ul></div>" );
} else {
// no query string exists
$p( "div#filterContainer" ).html( 
         "No filters are being applied." );
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Possibly, I've looked through that stack, but I still can't find what I am looking to achieve.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2880929/1008823 Seems to do exactly what you want, you get an array with all the url parameters that are represented in the url.